# Is there a method for accessing variables in the parent scopes of a function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, metaprogramming, symbols

Given a reference to a `function`, is it possible to access the variable names and/or values in its parent scopes? For example:

```js
let ref = (function myClosure() {
  const foo = 'foo';
  const bar = 'bar';
  
  return {
    sneaky() {
      // use the variables somehow
      // since some browsers optimize functions
      // by omitting parent scopes from the context
      // that are not used
      console.log(foo, bar);
    }
  };
}());

// given `ref.sneaky` in this scope, how to access the scope in `myClosure`?
console.log(ref);
```

Inspecting `ref` in the developer console, we find this:

[image: inspection of <code>ref</code>]

Notice the `Closure` object which contains `foo` and `bar`. If it is not possible to obtain this closure object programmatically, is there any currently proposed ECMAScript standard like say, `Symbol.scope` that could contain the array of parent "closure objects" of a given function?

### Update

To address @Bergi and @Oriol's comments, I'm adding some clarification.

```js
let ref = (function myClosure() {
  const foo = 'foo';
  const bar = 'bar';
  
  return {
    sneaky(...variableNames) {
      // use the variables somehow
      // since some browsers optimize functions
      // by omitting parent scopes from the context
      // that are not used
      console.log(foo, bar);
      
      return Object.assign(...variableNames.map(variableName => ({
          [variableName]: eval(variableName)
        })
      ));
    }
  };
}());

// given `ref.sneaky` in this scope, how to access the scope in `myClosure`?
console.log(ref.sneaky('foo', 'bar'));
```

Sure, this works if the variable names are known ahead of time, and if an `eval` exists in the child scope, but what if neither of these conditions are met?

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. If they were intended to be exposed publicly they would be

Comment: @charlietfl For me, this question is more of an intellectual exercise than something I intend to use. I'm just wondering if the method the console utility uses to display the closures from a function reference is accessible in JavaScript, and whether or not there's a standard proposal in progress for making this possible. I don't think it's valid to say this doesn't make sense just based on the alleged "intention" of scoping the variables, since this is a hypothetical situation anyway.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but doesn't `ref.sneaky()` work?

Comment: @Oriol no. What I'm asking about is access the the `Closure` object I showed in the screenshot. I'm currently in the middle of updating my question to clarify this.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ah, so you want to access the environment record, right? But that's an internal thing of the spec. Implementations are not even required to have them.

Comment: Should probably think of it as being able to see the closure in console is  a developer convenience. What doesn't make sense is changing ability to access local variables inside  closure programmatically unless author wants them to be exposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given a reference to a function, is it possible to programmatically access the variable names and/or values in its parent scopes?

No.

> Is there any currently proposed ECMAScript standard like say, `Symbol.scope` that could contain the array of parent "closure objects" of a given function?

No. And if there was, it would never get accepted, as closures are the only means of true encapsulation in javacript, and introducing such an accessor would be a gaping security hole (for references, see http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/PAPERS/2011/paper023.pdf or http://web.emn.fr/x-info/sudholt/papers/miss13.pdf).

Comment: I'm sorry, but saying that scoping is a security measure is absolutely ridiculous. As I've just demonstrated, even if it's not programmatically possible, it's clearly not going to stop anyone who intends to exploit the exposure of any client-side API methods or sensitive data "protected" by a scope. Why, then, do you say this proposal would never be accepted?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Because it would make exploits programmatically possible. The intention is not to protect the USER form themselves. The intention is to protect the USER form script injections of a third party agent.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: What did you demonstrate? A debugger is not programmatical access, and the user is not the threat. We're talking about security of third party scripts here.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense, I guess I hadn't considered that vector. I still think that scoping isn't going to protect anything though, a 3rd party script could still access the script as a string, strip the scope from it and evaluate it with an interpreter like Babel to obtain anything it wanted to know about the environment inside the scope, though that's probably extremely elaborate and tedious.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: "*access the script as a string*" - not necessarily. Restriction of APIs and mostly the same origin policy can prevent such. But yes, that's the kind of security one is concerned about.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the references, I'll definitely read those.